# Discord Non-async retrieve id by username

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I'm making a program that asks for a username in the console, and then finds out the id by it.
I wanted to use discord.py at first, but it cannot be used synchronously.
Then I decided to do it through the discord api, but the only thing that can help me is to `get guild members`, but I'm not sure what is the right way to do this.
And so, the question is - Is the correct way that I found or is it worth doing something else?
Any help would be welcome.
P.S. all users are on the same server as the bot.